# Cannot add image and save to pdf file using PDFKit

Tags: ios, pdf, apple-pdfkit

I have a class to edit pdf by inserting an image into the pdf and save a new pdf with the inserted image.

Below code is the way I use to achieve the scenario, by creating a custom `PDFAnnotation`. I specify type as `.widget` instead of `.stamp` to avoid having black line drawing across diagonal.

```swift
final private class PDFImageAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {

    var image: UIImage?

    convenience init(_ image: UIImage?, bounds: CGRect, properties: [AnyHashable: Any]?) {
        self.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget, withProperties: properties)
        self.image = image
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        super.draw(with: box, in: context)

        // Drawing the image within the annotation's bounds.
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return }
        context.draw(cgImage, in: bounds)
    }
}
```

Below is how I display pdf and select image to save in pdf

```swift
private func setupPDF() {
    guard let url = url else { return }
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    pdfView.autoScales = true
}

private func addImageAndSave(_ image: UIImage) {
    guard let page = pdfView.currentPage else { return }

    let pageBounds = page.bounds(for: .cropBox)
    let imageBounds = CGRect(x: pageBounds.midX, y: pageBounds.midY, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    let imageStamp = PDFImageAnnotation(image, bounds: imageBounds, properties: nil)
    imageStamp.shouldDisplay = true
    imageStamp.shouldPrint = true
    page.addAnnotation(imageStamp)

    // Save PDF with image
    let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
    let saveUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName, isDirectory: false)
    pdfView.document?.write(to: saveUrl)
}
```

However the result pdf file is below

The preview on right column does display the picture but when open the pdf in `Preview` app or any browser the picture is not there.

[image]

How can I make the picture appear in the final pdf file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to also draw that image on `PDFPage` to make them appear in the saved pdf file

```swift
final private class ImagePDFPage: PDFPage {

    /// A flag indicates whether to draw image on a page
    /// 
    /// - Note: Set this to `true` before write pdf to file otherwise the image will not be appeared in pdf file
    var saveImageToPDF: Bool = false

    private var imageAnnotation: EkoPDFImageAnnotation? = nil


    func addImageAnnotation(_ annotation: EkoPDFImageAnnotation) {
        imageAnnotation = annotation
        addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    func removeImageAnnotation() {
        guard let imageAnnotation = imageAnnotation else { return }
        self.imageAnnotation = nil
        removeAnnotation(imageAnnotation)
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, to context: CGContext) {
        super.draw(with: box, to: context)

        guard saveImageToPDF,
              let annotation = imageAnnotation,
              let cgImage = annotation.image?.cgImage else { return }
        context.draw(cgImage, in: annotation.bounds)
    }
}
```

and update `PDFDocument.delegate` to tell to use `ImagePDFPage` as a class for pdf page

```swift
extension PDFEditorViewController: PDFDocumentDelegate {
    func classForPage() -> AnyClass {
        return ImagePDFPage.self
    }
}
```

The result

[image]