# Convert Swift UIImage to UIBezierPath

Tags: swift

Can I convert my UIImage to a BezierPath in Swift? I converted it from a BezierPath to a UIImage with the following line.

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage.shapeImageWithBezierPath(bezierPath: path, fillColor: .white, strokeColor: .black)
```

When I pull my image back from my database it's in base64, so I convert it back into an image with the following code.

```
let stringData = Data(base64Encoded: mydata)
let uiImage = UIImage(data: stringData!)
```

I am unsure how to convert from an Image back to a BezierPath.

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: This is an unusual problem, why would you need to convert a bezier path from an image? What are you trying to extract from that image?

Comment: @Cristik I’m trying to pull a signature because the bezier path can be displayed in an annotation field in pdfkit, but I haven’t discovered a way to do so with an image yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662970/swift-pdfkit-put-image-in-image-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot convert to `UIBezierPath` once it's converted to an `UIImage`.

You can only add additional `UIBezierPath`'s to the `UIImage` that's been created from `base64` data but not the other way around.